# PyQT5 general, updating main window?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

**Example:** Windows explorer, when you have a folder, and you double click it. The new information appears in the same screen, rather than opening a new window.

I'm using PyQt5. In QtDesigner, I can't see any way of creating new 'layers' to switch between. I have buttons on a banner along the top, that when you click will take you to a new page, how could I achieve this? I can't see any way of linking these pages.